# Set default application based on filename not mimetype

Tags: filenames, mime-types, xdg-open

I want to define an application for opening files based on the filename.

For example I want a file called `Gemfile` or `Dockerfile` to be opened with sublime or atom.

I know I can use the mime-type but for both files it will be `text/plain`.

Or is there a mime-type for `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Matching based on filename is one of the easiest ways to define a mimetype.
There is no official mimetype for Gemfiles or Dockerfiles,
but take a look in `/usr/share/mime/packages/`
and you will find many unofficial mimetypes
that have `<sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>`
and are typically named `text/x-*`,
such as `text/x-python` or `text/x-markdown`.

Adding custom mimetypes is generally straightforward,
especially in this case where we can just use the filename.

As you observed the current mimetype
of a `Dockerfile` and `Gemfile` are both `text/plain`:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype Dockerfile 
text/plain
$ xdg-mime query filetype Gemfile 
text/plain
```

We will create a new mimetype `text/x-dockerfile` for files named `Dockerfile`
or `*.dockerfile` and a new mimetype `text/x-gemfile` for files named `Gemfile`.
To accomplish this,
create an XML file named `x-dockerfile.xml` with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="text/x-dockerfile">
        <comment>Dockerfile</comment>
        <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
        <glob pattern="Dockerfile"/>
        <glob pattern="*.dockerfile"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and another file named `x-gemfile.xml` with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="text/x-gemfile">
        <comment>Gemfile</comment>
        <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
        <glob pattern="Gemfile"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Next, install the mimetypes.
For a local user, run these commands:

```
xdg-mime install --mode user x-dockerfile.xml
xdg-mime install --mode user x-gemfile.xml
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

To install system-wide, run these commands:

```
xdg-mime install --mode system x-dockerfile.xml
xdg-mime install --mode system x-gemfile.xml
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Observe that the detected mimetypes have now changed.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype Dockerfile 
text/x-dockerfile
$ xdg-mime query filetype Gemfile
text/x-gemfile
```

Now you can assign these to whichever text editor you prefer.