# How to associate a new (custom) mime type with files (based on file extension)?

Tags: mime-types, xdg-open

This is part 2 of [How to install a new (custom) mime type on my Linux system using CLI tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564816/how-to-install-a-new-custom-mime-type-on-my-linux-system-using-cli-tools)

Using the steps in the accepted answer at the above question, I created the following mime-type mx-publickey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
<mime-type type="text/x-publickey">
<comment>Custom type for public key files (plain text)</comment>
    <glob-deleteall/>
    <glob pattern="*.pub"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I installed it system-wide with this command:

```
# xdg-mime install --mode system mx-publickey.xml
```

I added the desired icon:

```
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 256 x-publickey-icon.png text-x-publickey
```

Then I tested it. My '*.pub` files still have the old association:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype id_rsa_test.pub
text/plain

$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
org.kde.kate.desktop
```

**What additional steps are required to associate '*.pub` files with my new mime-type?**

Edit:

I performed the following steps, but `*.pub` public key files are still not being opened by default with Kate from Electron applications.

```
# xdg-mime default  org.kde.kate.desktop text/x-publickey

# xdg-mime query default text/x-publickey
org.kde.kate.desktop

$ xdg-mime query default text/x-publickey
org.kde.kate.desktop
```

Next I used the GUI tools (KDE System Settings > Applications > File Associations) and associated `*.pub`  public key files with Kate. **Electron applications still refuse to open `*.pub` files with Kate.**

Electron apps previously used Okular. Afer the `xdg-mime default` command shown above, **the Okular association is gone, but nothing has replaced it**. Electron apps now present a KIO dialog asking me to pick the application to use. (That's better than forcing me to use the wrong application, but it is still not correct behavior. It appears Electron applications are looking other places for the file associations. I would like to understand that.)

Am I missing a needed `.desktop` file in some location?

Another thought: After the above steps, I believe I should now see an entry for `text/x-publickey` in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. However, there is not one.

Comment: What would be an example Electron app that would display this behavior? For example, is there one in the Arch package repositories?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver This is the one that I'm having this issue with: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/riot-desktop/

Comment: Ah, I see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565204/click-link-to-download-a-file-but-kde-tries-to-open-it-with-an-application-how

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix the Electron app issues, but it should be of general use.

Comment: Nice answer. I accepted it even before testing it! I will try it over the next few days and report back if I have any issues. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324038/set-default-application-based-on-filename-not-mimetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`shared-mime-info` repository](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/shared-mime-info/)
already specifies the `application/pgp-keys` mimetype.
You can see it here:

```
<mime-type type="application/pgp-keys">
  <comment>PGP keys</comment>
  <acronym>PGP</acronym>
  <expanded-acronym>Pretty Good Privacy</expanded-acronym>
  <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
  <generic-icon name="text-x-generic"/>
  <magic priority="50">
    <match type="string" value="-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" offset="0"/>
    <match type="string" value="-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----" offset="0"/>
    <match type="big16" value="0x9501" offset="0"/>
    <match type="big16" value="0x9500" offset="0"/>
    <match type="big16" value="0x9900" offset="0"/>
    <match type="big16" value="0x9901" offset="0"/>
  </magic>
  <glob pattern="*.skr"/>
  <glob pattern="*.pkr"/>
  <glob pattern="*.asc" weight="10"/>
  <glob pattern="*.pgp"/>
  <glob pattern="*.gpg"/>
  <glob pattern="*.key"/>
</mime-type>
```

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/blob/6bf9e4ff0fb7eff11a02bd937045bf5dc291841a/data/freedesktop.org.xml.in#L282

or here on your own machine:

`/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`

However, it does not use the `*.pub` glob pattern,
probably to avoid conflicts with MS Publisher format.
One workaround is just to rename the files as e.g. `*.asc` files.
But let's continue on, assuming that renaming the files is not an option.
Here is the mimeinfo file we need
(note that it *must* be named `pgp-keys.xml`):

```
$ cat pgp-keys.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/pgp-keys">
        <comment>PGP keys</comment>
        <acronym>PGP</acronym>
        <expanded-acronym>Pretty Good Privacy</expanded-acronym>
        <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
        <generic-icon name="text-x-generic"/>
        <magic priority="10">
          <match value="-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" type="string" offset="0"/>
        </magic>
        <glob weight="10" pattern="*.pub"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

The advantage of the "magic" part
is that it will look at the beginning of the file for this string,
then determine the mimetype based on whether or not it matches.
This means that files with mimetype `application/vnd.ms-publisher`
can still have the `.pub` file extension
and live in relative harmony
alongside public keys that also have the `.pub` file extension.
To achieve this, we must install the mimeinfo file.

To install it for a single user:

```
xdg-mime install --mode user pgp-keys.xml
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

To install it system-wide:

```
sudo xdg-mime install --mode system pgp-keys.xml
sudo /usr/bin/update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

I've tested the outcome with an example public key from here:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/pgp-public-key.html

and an example MS Publisher file from here:

https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/0bf11aec86079b8f1ae2f1ea680910ba79665c4f/tika-parsers/src/test/resources/test-documents/testPUBLISHER.pub

You can try it yourself with the git repository here:

https://github.com/nbeaver/custom-pub-file-mimetype